# Pycharm produces error in my comments and my correct codes

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm 3.0 with python 2.7.
The problem is that when I'm coding, Pycharm is underlining my code which I'm sure its correct. when I cut the line of code and paste again it has not errors!
The funny part is that Pycharm is underlining my codes in the comment as errors as you can see in the picture. what should I do?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `File | Invalidate caches...` yet ?

Answer (score -1):

Try inspect the code.

> Code > Inspect Code

Choose the options: Whole project, File or Custom scope.

The underlines are possibly spelling or indentation; for the spelling the solution is: 
Save 'word' to dictionary.

Comment: Spelling underlines are not red! and also its not what I've asked. the problem is happening again and again.